# lists of lists haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have a simple question, i am new to Haskell and trying to learn a lot.
How can i concatenate for example

```
 [( (0,1) , [1,2,3]) , ((1,2) , [7,8,9]) ,((0,1) , [4,5,6]) ] to [[1,2,3,4,5,6] , [7,8,9]]
```

I want to concatenate the lists that  have first element of the pair equal.
I tried

```
 map concat list 

 map (\t -> (filter (==).first) list ) list
```

but the first one doesn't work and the second one gives an error.
Any ideas?

Comment: You're on the right track. Have you looked at [`groupBy`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=groupBy)?

Answer (score 2):

using a couple functions from `Data.List` and `Data.Function.on` this becomes:

```
import Data.List     (sortBy, groupBy)
import Data.Function (on)

sortByFirst :: Ord a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
sortByFirst = sortBy (compare `on` fst)
```

the `groupBy` functions expect that the data is sorted, so we must first sort by each inner tuple (i.e. sort by `(a, b)` in `((a, b), [x,y,z])`)

```
groupByFirst :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> [[(a, b)]]
groupByFirst = groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
```

then we use `groupBy` to group the resulting list of tuples into *lists* of lists of tuples, where each inner list shares the same first element.

```
squishByFirst :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [(a, b)] -> [[b]]
squishByFirst = (map . concatMap) snd . groupByFirst . sortByFirst
```

then we use some fancy mapping over `snd` to roll into each inner list, pull out the second element (the list), combine them together, and give back the result. This is equivalent to:

```
squishByFirst xs =
  let grouped = groupByFirst . sortByFirst $ xs
  in  [concat [ys | (_, ys) <- g] | g <- grouped]
```

---

You can also implement this as a fold over `Map.insertWith`

```
import Data.Map (elems, empty, insertWith)

squishByFirst :: Ord k => [(k, [v])] -> [[v]]
squishByFirst = elems . mkMap
  where
  mkMap = foldr (uncurry (insertWith (++))) empty
```

or for any Monoid:

```
squishByFirst :: (Ord k, Monoid vs) => [(k, vs)] -> [vs]
squishByFirst = elems . mkMap
  where
  mkMap = foldr (uncurry (insertWith mappend)) empty
```

Comment: Good answer. I think `map (concatMap snd)` is clearer than  `(map . concatMap) snd` though. Sounds picky but it stalled me for a bit.

Comment: @JordanMackie that's a common Haskell idiom though. `f (g x) == (f . g) x`